# How to update unittests when migrating from sqlite to postgres (django)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-unittest, pytest-django

I have a somewhat large Django project with many views/models. I recently migrated my project from sqlite3 to postgres locally, and plan to scale it out even further (put postgres on a separate machine, etc).

I followed [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/sirodoht/f598d14e9644e2d3909629a41e3522ad) when I migrated from sqlite to postgres, and it appears to have worked perfectly. (ie, my running app looks identical to when the db was sqlite)

**My issue is this:** When I run my previously-written unittests, the first unittest works and all proceeding unittests fail. Individually, the unittests work fine. I've seen some [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815872/testing-postgres-db-python) on stackoverflow that addressed this issue, but the solutions were so unclear. How can I rework my `setUp()`/ `teardown()` methods for my unittests so that they will pass with my newly migrated postgres db? Do i need to completely rewrite all unittests?

I've seen the [pytest-postgresql library](https://pytest-pgsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), although I'm not entirely sure how to modify my unittests based off of this.

My testing suite is set up with different classes that test views. So for example,

```
class View1Tests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        c1 = Category.objects.create(id=55555, leaf_node_name="Test Category 1")
        c2 = Category.objects.create(id=12345, leaf_node_name="Test Category 2")

        s1 = Search.objects.create(category=c1, username="testuser")
        s2 = Search.objects.create(category=c2, username="testuser2")


    def test_view1_success(self):
         #blablabla

    def test_view1_fail(self):
         #blablabla

    def test_view1_something(self):
         #blablabla
```

I'm getting errors like this:

> appname.models.DoesNotExist: Search matching query does not exist.

Again, all of these unittests run perfectly fine when sqlite3 was the db. I think its an issue with the postgres testing settings? But I'm at a loss as to where to even begin. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but presumably your test classes extend `django.test.TestCase` and you're running your tests with `python manage.py test`?

Comment: @WillKeeling my tests extend django.test.TestCase. However, I am running `pytest` to run all the tests. Running `python manage.py test` also throws identical errors though.

Comment: @HeidiLyons: did you manage to solve this problem? I'm in the same spot now. Would be great if you could post what worked for you! Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting this same error when moving from sqlite to postgresql. I'll post a reply if I ever figure out what the issue is

Comment: I think I found the solution. Solution is posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally figured out the problem. The issue arises when trying to fetch an object by the default primary key (e.g. `MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)`, `MyModel.objects.get(id=1)`). My assumption is that Postgres uses a serial data type as the AutoField and the value of the increment depends on the sequence generated by Postgres.

The solution I found is really simple. Either fetch by an attribute that has a unique property for that object, or fetch all objects and filter using list indexing. The latter method shouldn't be too cumbersome since in most cases, a few instances of the model are created.

### Here's a full example

```
# models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(
        max_length=13,
        primary_key=True  # uniqueness is enforced
    )
    book_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        unique=True  # another unique field
    )
    author_count = models.IntegerField()
    book_genre = models.CharField(max_length=64)


# tests.py
class MyTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # first object
        Book.objects.create(
            isbn='10101',
            book_name='Binary Code',
            author_count=1,
            book_genre='Fiction'
        )

        # second object
        Book.objects.create(
            isbn='314159',
            book_name='Life of Pi',
            author_count=1,
            book_genre='Philosophy'
        )

    def setUp(self):
        self.book1 = Book.objects.all()[0]
        # or self.book1 = Book.objects.get(isbn='10101')
        # or self.book1 = Book.objects.get(book_name='Binary Code')
        self.book2 = Book.objects.all()[1]
        # or self.book2 = Book.objects.get(isbn='314159')
        # or self.book2 = Book.objects.get(book_name='Life of Pi')

    def test_something(self):
        # lastly, since `setUp` is called before every test_* method
        # you can just access the instance's attributes without calling `get`
        # e.g:
        self.assertEqual(self.book1.book_genre, 'Fiction')

    def test_something_else(self):
        # you an also reload the instance using `refresh_from_db`
        # after making changes
        Book.objects.filter(author_count=1).update(book_genre='Fiction')
        self.book2.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(self.book2.book_genre, 'Fiction')
```

Comment: Why does this happen though?

Comment: I have a question... I want to test PATCH and DELETE methods which require the id of the model to be provided. How do I test for this, the id's are kinda random.

Previously, I was using sqlite but then after migrating to postgres, these tests started to fail.

Comment: @GoutamBSeervi as mentioned in my answer, use list indexing to grab the records as opposed to fetching by ID. This should allow you to test the other methods.

Comment: That's a lot of work.. I'll have to rewrite all my tests. I have been stuck on this error for a day now 

Comment: I was able to solve this by replacing TestCase with TransactionTestCase, now my tests work fine...but they take more time now. xD

It used to take around a second earlier..now it's 70 seconds

Comment: That makes sense considering TransactionTestCases will have the db commit and then rollback after each test. Thanks for sharing.